# Move icons in the middle of icon-div

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I have the following icon-div. What I want is to align the elements in the middle of the div like shown in the wireframe. What shall I do to make this happen.

HTML:

```
<div class="icons_div">
    <div class="row bg-secondary">
        <div class="col-sm-2"> 
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"> 
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"> 
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"> 
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i> </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icons_div
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: content;
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 15px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.fa
{
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Following are my wireframe and my output respectively:

[image: Wireframe]

[image: My Output]

Comment: You could e.g. use some "spacer" divs at the left and the right

Comment: Add a working example please.

Comment: Can you not reduce the width of `icons_div` ?

Comment: Using my code to post new questions without accepting my answers? Not nice!...

Comment: Which answer @WebDevBooster? I dont exactly remember.. I accept all the answers that are useful to me, let me check again and I will get back to you

Comment: The answer where I posted that code that you've been using.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstraps flexbox: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

with

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-circle"> </i></div>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </div>
    ...
</div>
```

you can justify them with "margins" left and right
if you want to put this more into the center, you can set a margin on the flex container or around it

Comment: Some reason for referencing the alpha docs? Bootstrap is currently in release 4.0.0, and the flex docs can be found on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Good to get that fixed :)